# Stop time on mouse movement or click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, session

I want to stop the timer when I move the mouse or press a key. This is what I have so far and it works by counting down the time. Im not sure what needs to be done to stop the time. (code is from this page: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Automatically-redirect-User-after-Session-Timeout-in-ASPNet.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SessionExpireAlert(timeout) {


        var seconds = timeout / 1000;
        document.getElementsByName("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
        document.getElementsByName("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;


        setInterval(function() {
            seconds--;
            document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
            document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            //Show Popup before 20 seconds of timeout.
            $find("mpeTimeout").show();
        }, timeout - 20 * 1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = "login.aspx";
        }, timeout);
    };
    function ResetSession() {
        //Redirect to refresh Session.
        window.location = window.location.href;
    }
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        //Code goes here (Need help here)

    });
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        //Code goes here (Need help here)

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect inactivity and warn the user he will be logged out, you can do like this :

Working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/newzy08/dun6gbvx/
you can combine with a sweetAlert popup warn : http://jsfiddle.net/kbLqu1ah/21/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                var time = 3000 ; //session timeout 3 seconds for the tests
                var timeout;
                var isLogout = false;

                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    //Things you need to do
                        isLogout = true; 
                        alert("logged out !");

                }, time);

                $(document).on('mousemove keypress', function () {
                    if (!isLogout) {
                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                            //Things you need to do
                             isLogout = true;
                             alert("logged out !");
                        }, time);
                    }
                });
            });
```

If the user moves his mouse or press a key, it stops the 3 seconds countdown, and it restarts it...
When no activity after 3 seconds, the alert() code is executed

You can use the library SweetAlert2 for having a pretty message in the popup, cf https://sweetalert2.github.io/
Sample code with countdown message : http://jsfiddle.net/kbLqu1ah/4/

Comment: Can we have an alert that allows the user to stay on the page?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to display a sweetalert popup with for instance a 5 minutes countdown, and a button "Keep connected"...if the user clicks on this button, he keeps connected, otherwise the popup at the end of the countdown redirects to the logout page...  Sweetalert2 has sample of countdown, see their example called "A message with auto close timer"

Comment: I've added sample code for autologout popup warning, cf my answer below, and this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kbLqu1ah/4/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to wrap you seconds-- in a if statement. For example:

```
 if(noMovement){
      seconds--;
      ...
 }

 $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
    noMovement=false;
});

$(this).keypress(function(e) {
    noMovement=false;
});
```